# iPad iOS 6 How prevent top corners UINavigationBar from rounding with background image

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uinavigationbar

I have found a lot of posts on this but so far no luck. I am targeting iOS 6.0 and have a custom background image for my navigation bar. The top 2 corners are rounding and I have not found a way to prevent this. I've tried setting the status bar to black translucent (seems you can't do this on the iPad) but no luck. I'm attaching a screenshot (see the blue is rounded on the top edges). Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: I think it kind of looks nice how it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all, your app looks great.**

Second, that rounding is something that the status bar itself does - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5530981/1849664). So, there *is* a way - get rid of the status bar.

However, your app doesn't look like the type that it would make sense to have the status bar go away. If I were you, I would just leave it as-is - it looks **great** how it is.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! Going to keep the rounded corners.

Answer (score 2):

I agree it looks fine the way it is.

If you do want to remove the rounded edges but still keep the status bar, I would check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607073/top-corners-of-uinavigationbar-are-being-rounded-off-in-ios6).

Comment: Thanks. I am going to keep it as it is, but for the record I did try this solution, but it seems you can't set the status bar to black translucent for the iPad. At least it didn't change anything for me when I did.